# How to show only changed files in Android Studio?

Tags: xcode, android-studio, intellij-idea

Is there an alternative to the Xcode button "Show only files with source-control status" in Android Studio?

It sorts the files and only shows in Project Files Navigator the ones you have modified.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see files to commit you can use cmd+k (mac).
Also you can open "Commit" panle on the left edge.

Answer (score 2):

You can view all changed files in the Git tool window (assuming you use Git), under the Local Changes tab. Alternatively you can click on the down arrow at the top of the Project (Cmd+1) view and select All Changed Files.

Answer (score 2):

In the `Project` Tool window in Android Studio there is a dropdown list where you can select `All Changed Files`.

[image: Project Tool Window dropdown]

Comment: Other than the screenshot, how is this any different from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70743743/10871073)?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Only One Work Around]

Besides the git option, we have a setting to close unmodified files.